# Symfony2 Twig printing variable related entity properties

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am having some trouble trying to access variables in twig.

I have a class called staff and a class called image

every staff has 1 image_id which maps to the image table

I can call the following code in php to access the image url

```
//...get 1 staff member
echo $staff->getImage()->getWebPath();
```

However calling this code in twig does not seem to work

```
{{ staff.image.webpath }}
```

If I pull the image in php and pass it to the template i can access it like so

```
php
---
$image = $staff->getImage();

twig
----
{{ image.webpath }}
```

I would like to pass all staff to my template and then use a for loop to print out their names bios titles and images. Is this possible to do with the Image?

Comment: Do You have a getImage() function in Staff entity ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will define the __toString method in the image entity like this:

`public function __toString() {
return $this->getWebPath();
}`

Then you will access variable in the Twig like:

`<img src="{{ staff.image }}" alt="image" />`